# Find the local maxima in a sequence of values

Tags: arrays, algorithm

What algorithm can we use to find the local maxima in a randomly generated value array of length 10?

My current strategy is to break the array into 3 and find the maximum element of each subset array, but that does not include all the maxima.

[image: Line graph]

Ideally, I would like the first point to also be identified as a local maximum, and the third red from left should not be marked as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just go through all the indices and compare that element to the two elements on either side, skipping the check if it's on the edge.

Pseudo-code:

```
for each index
  if     (index == 0              or array[index-1] < array[index])
     and (index == array.length-1 or array[index+1] < array[index])
  {
    store index
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To find local maximae usually you can use [hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing). Additionally you could improve it by applying [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) to avoid stopping at a local maximum instead of a bigger maximum after it.